# How to compare task completion times in a crossover study

Tags: hypothesis-testing, repeated-measures, survival, statistical-power, crossover-study

Ten participants have completed a task using two different methods A and B. The first five participants completed the task first using method A then B. The remaining participants completed the same task first using method B then A. The following shows the completion times (minutes) of each method and the order in which the methods were used for each participant.

```
                 Time to complete task using
                         (in minutes):
Participant ID      Method A      Method B     Used Method A Before Method B
1                      17            9                       True
2                       8            5                       True
3                      18            8                       True
4                      19           19                       True
5                      37           11                       True
6                      19           18                       False
7                       9            8                       False
8                      12           11                       False
9                      16           18                       False
10                     13           10                       False
```

1. Is it possible to make a valid statistical argument about the difference between the completion times of the two methods A and B?
2. Is the number of participants large enough to make a valid statistical comparison between the completion time of the two methods?
3. What statistical tests can be applied to compare the completion time of the two methods A and B?
4. Is the difference between the completion times of the two methods A and B statistically significant?

Comment: Welcome to the site, @reprogrammer. Note that we can give you some information about questions 1-3, but running the analysis & determining if the methods differ (ie #4) is your job.

Comment: I'd appreciate answers to the first three questions.